# sending array in cookie using express is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, cookies

I am currently working on a project, where I need to give the user an array. For that, I am trying to use the res.cookie() function. However, whenever I try to give the user an array as cookie data, the browser gets the data as a string (also adding a "j" that i cannot understand).

backend code:

```
homepageRouter.get('/',(req,res) => {
res.cookie("likedProjects", "checkstring");
res.cookie("supportedProjects", [2500,4,6]);
res.sendFile('/pages/homepage.html',{root:rootDir});
```

});

The "checkstring" works just fine but when I look at the second cookie its data comes off as a string:

```
j:[2500,4,6]
```

Is there a way to ensure that the cookie data will be received in the browser as an array?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you might be doing something wrong, I think. Do you use any cookie parsing middleware(`cookie-parser` is the official one for express.js)? I have tried to reproduce your issue like this with `cookie-parser` and I get a normal array that is not a string.

```js
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());
app.get("/set", (req, res) => {
  res.cookie("hi", [12, 12, 12])
  res.send("hi");
  // For the sake of this example I wrote it this way but you can also do
  // res.cookie("hi", [1,2,3]).send("hi")
});
app.get("/log", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.cookies.hi);
  res.send(`logged in console this value also: ${req.cookies.hi}`)
});

app.listen("4433");
```

Hope this helped

Comment: I have tried using the cookie parser, but when I used it the browser was stuck on the request (probably because there was no cookie in the beginning). How can I fix it? Add a dummy cookie in the first page?

Comment: Are you actually getting to sending the response? Are there any errors? Check your console

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON stringify

```
homepageRouter.get('/',(req,res) => {
    res.cookie("likedProjects", "checkstring");
    res.cookie("supportedProjects", JSON.stringify([2500,4,6]) );
    res.sendFile('/pages/homepage.html',{root:rootDir});
```

Then rertrieving

```
const json_str = getCookie('supportedProjects');
const arr = JSON.parse(json_str);
```